# php not friendly with date format d/m/Y

Tags: php, html, sql

I can't convert date to format `d/m/Y`.

`date("d-m-Y", strtotime(substr($code, 22, 6)) );` return `21-10-2014`

but `date("d/m/Y", strtotime(substr($code, 22, 6)) );` return 21/10/2014
How to format?

Comment: What do you mean? it is formatted?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Code is missing (literary `$code`). We have no clue what the expected output is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [**`DateTime`**](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to create an object with your format, and then reformat it.

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('ymd', '140521');
echo $date->format('d/m/y'); //Output: 21/05/14
```

https://eval.in/208227

Comment: My string is in format 140521 and i need to tell script that is date in format d/m/y

Comment: Check the edit :) I assumed your current format was ymd

Answer (score 1):

How would you like your formated date be displayed? The d, m and y in "d-m-Y" or "d/m/Y" are responsible for what you wish to display, not - or /

Here is a few list of parameters and their output:

d : Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros 01-31

m : Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros 01-12

Y : A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits

F : A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March

l : A full textual representation of the day of the week Sunday through Saturday

If you want to display 21 October 2014, you will have to use:

```
date("d F Y", strtotime(substr($code, 22, 6)) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$originalDate = "2014-10-21";
$newDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```

(see [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) and [date](http://php.net/date) docs on the PHP site).